# The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested

Tags: java, android, gradle

Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.

The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[11.0.2,11.0.2], [15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 15.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

I have this error when build the app and this is my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.radon.vitrin"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    implementation files('libs/CircleImageViewmaster/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar')
    implementation files('libs/picasso-2.5.2(1).jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'

    //noinspection GradleCompatible

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation ('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
        // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try downgrade firebase dependency from 16.0.1 to 16.0.0. If this doesn't work then try upgrading google play services dependency

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:16.0.0'` to make it work.

Comment: sir i have tried but got same error again not working for me?

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure to keep Your Google play services dependencies and Firebase dependencies to latest version

**Check here for Google play services update version**

[Google Play Services Latest](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

**Check here for Firebase updated version**

[Firebase Latest](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases)

**Check here for Firebase updated version for Android**

[Firebase Android Latest](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)

Answer (score 0):

Current problem is solved working with the latest features of firebase dependencies.
Make sure you work with the most recent dependencies.

[image: gradle (module.app)]

afeter this sync project

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me ended up being that the gradle plugin was out of date, so it didn't know how to properly resolve everything that I'd just updated. Find the latest version [here.](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following Gradle dependency to ​remove ambiguity in GMS version:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2'
```